# How to understand why android can't install apk file?

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, apk

I use existing project in Eclipse.

It is an Android application.

Eclipse shows no build error in the project.

I can Run it As Android Application on my Android device. No problems.

When I build apk file using Export - Export Android Appliction, copy apk file on Android device and try to run (Install) it ask for installing

[image]

when press Install it shows Installing... string for sometime 
then show Application not installed.

[image]

How to understand the cause of the error?
Get more detailed information about why the program failed to install?

I have Eclipse 4.2.2

Project build target 4.0.3

Android version of the phone is 5.0.1

Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.syclo.agentry.client.android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="70010000"
    android:versionName="70.10.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.syclo.agentry.client.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.syclo.agentry.client.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission-group
        android:name="com.syclo.agentry.client.android.permission.group.AGENTRY"
        android:description="@string/permission_group_agentry_description"
        android:label="@string/permission_group_agentry_label" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.syclo.agentry.client.android.permission.AGENTRY_IPC"
        android:description="@string/permission_ipc_description"
        android:label="@string/permission_ipc_label"
        android:permissionGroup="com.syclo.agentry.client.android.permission.group.AGENTRY"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

    <application
        android:name=".AgentryAndroidClient"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.StartupActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name_short"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.NoTitleBar.FullScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_short"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.NoTitleBar.FullScreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.ServerSelectionActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/server_select"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.LogoutDialogActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name_short"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.IdleTimeoutActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/welcome"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.ModuleMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/module_menu"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.AboutBoxActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.PasswordChangeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/passwd_change_title"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.builtin.TransmitActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/transmit_title"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.screensets.TabbedScreenSetActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.screensets.WizardScreenSetActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryDefault.ActionBar"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.screensets.OverlayScreenSetActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AgentryActivityDialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ipc.IntentReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.syclo.agentry.client.android.permission.AGENTRY_IPC"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".ui.builtin.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.syclo.agentry.client.android" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.syclo.agentry.client.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".ui.builtin.TimeZoneChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />

                <category android:name="com.syclo.agentry.client.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ZNFC"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_znfc" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It sounds like you have the app already installed, but with a different signature. If so, you have to uninstall it first.

Comment: Yes, it helped. The problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `goto -> Settings -> Applications -> findyourapp` and Uninstall it, it will works/or installed after that.